# How to update a field value in db with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to make activation = 1 in database, I have this code in class.php:

```
 public function activate($activation,$id){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `segments` SET `activation` = '$activation' WHERE `id` = '$id'")
                            or die($this->conn->error);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            $this->conn->close();
            return true;
        }
```

And this in activate.php:

```
<?php 

require_once 'class.php';
if(ISSET($_POST['activate'])){  

            $activation = '1';
    $conn = new db_class();
    $conn->activate($activation,$id);
    echo '
        <script>alert("Updated Successfully")</script>;
        <script>window.location = "index.php"</script>;
    ';
}
```

and here the code in index.php:

```
<form action="activate.php" method="post"> 

                                        <td><center> <button class = "btn btn-success" name="activate"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate</button></center></td>
                            </form>
```

so the problem is this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\segments\activate.php on line 8

please any help? thanks in advance(im new to mysqli oop)!

Comment: This notice is because you have not defined variable `$id`

Comment: where do i have to define it? in database the id is equal to id @programmingArrow

Comment: If the user is logged in you can set session and assign id to session variable

Comment: there is no session required only this, i dont want a login system @programmingArrow

Comment: you can set hidden field in your form and pass id value using post like you are doing to pass activate value

Comment: can u write me the code please and where exactly thank u @programmingArrow

Answer (score 0):

In your form do this:

```
<form action="activate.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">        
  <td><center> <button class = "btn btn-success" name="activate"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate</button></center></td>
</form>
```

Then in activate.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'class.php';
if(ISSET($_POST['activate'])){  

    $activation = '1';
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
    $conn = new db_class();
    $conn->activate($activation,$id);
    echo '
        <script>alert("Updated Successfully")</script>;
        <script>window.location = "index.php"</script>;
    ';
}
```

> I have used a constant value of id to give you idea how you can do this, you can change this value to dynamic value

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id"> is not working

Comment: You need to fetch records from database